# Use grep for extract text between two word

Tags: json, grep, jq

I hava a file:

```
{
   "test1": [
        "test_a",
        "test_b",
        "test_c"
   ]
}
```

I am trying to extract the text that exists between `"test1": [` and `]`
I'm trying this command:

```
cat test | grep -o -P '(?<=test": [).*(?=])'
```

But it's not work. An idea?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Simply with **`jq`** tool:

```
jq -r '.test1[]' testfile
```

The output:

```
test_a
test_b
test_c
```

Comment: Upvoting for jq... This is the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 2):

grep is not the best tool for this particular job, but if you must use it, this works:

```
cat test | grep -Pzo '(?s)(?<=test1\": \[)[^\]]*(?=\])'
```

With the input above you specified, the output of this command is:

```
    "test_a",
    "test_b",
    "test_c"
```

The -z option allows a pattern to match across multiple lines, in this case. The (?s) flag enables the [^\]] pattern to also match newline characters.

The jq utility is designed for what you're trying to do:

```
cat test | jq '.["test"]'
```

Comment: very nice solution. I did not know the `-z` option. To improve the post, could you update the formatting and maybe show the output.

Answer (score 1):

Update: unexpectedly `grep` is sadly able to grep over multiple lines. See some other answers. And `jq` is realy tje right tool for the job.

Nonetheless, here is an `awk` solution :

```
$ awk '/]/{p=0}p{print}/test1/{p=1}' test 
    "test_a",
    "test_b",
    "test_c"
```

Or a bit more generic

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="\"test1\": \\[\n|\n[[:blank:]]*\\]"}(RT~/]/){print}' test
    "test_a",
    "test_b",
    "test_c"
```

The first solution searches for `test1` and sets a marker to print (`p=1`). If it finds a `]` it will set the print marker to zero.

The second solution defines a record separator to be or `\"test1\": \\[\n` or `\n[[:blank:]]*\\]`. It will check the found record separator, if this is the correct one, it will print.

Comment: I know, I just kept it in the style of the OP. But you are correct, I'll update

Answer (score 0):

`sed -n '/"test1": \[/,/\]/{//!p}' test`

- `sed -n` only print lines from pattern buffer (modified input stream) when `p` command is used.
- From pattern `/"test1": \[/` to pattern `/\]/` using the `/START/,/END/{ ... }` syntax:
- `//!p` print the line only if not matching the previous match

The generic form is `sed -n '/START/,/END/{//!p}' input-file` to omit START and END lines.  Or simply `sed -n '/START/,/END/p' input-file` if you want them.